# UIPopoverController strange behavior

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I am using a UIPopoverController and populating it with a MPMediaPickerController to choose songs from iPod library. I have got it working just fine. However, I added a completely unrelated feature ( touch a button and image scale to large size ) and now the UIPopoverController behaves strangely only after using the new feature.

After using the button scale feature, the UIPopoverController appears in a strange manner. It looks like it is animating from a rotated state off the screen and lands in the correct place, but the expected behavior is that it should just appear in the right location.

```
// code for if the interface is a an iPhone, do not use popup     
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

//  code if not iPhone uses popover media picker

```
else {
    UIPopoverController* pop = 
    [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:picker];
    self.currentPop = pop;
```

// checks if the iPad is portrait or landscape and displays the popover media picker accordingly

```
    if (vertMode == TRUE) 
    {
```

// if in portrait mode

```
       [pop presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(668.0f, 846.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:NO];
```

// otherwise if in landscape mode

```
    }

    else if (vertMode == FALSE)

    {

       [pop presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(900.0f, 580.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:NO];


    }

  [pop release];

}
```

}

Comment: What happens if you start in portrait, show your popover and then rotate to landscape?

Answer (score 2):

OK, well I feel a bit silly answering my own question, but I hope that it may help someone else in the future.

I am not exactly sure why, but in my function for the button that scales the image to a large size, I forgot to add:

```
 [UIView commitAnimations];
```

the intention of that was to complete the animated movement of the scaling image, I am guessing because I never commit the animation, that it was still in some state of trying to animating things. Then when I called my popup , it made the weird animation occur.

So I fixed this by just adding the above one line!

I feel SO much better figuring this one out! I hope it helps someone else out there.